# How to login to external machine?

Tags: python, authentication, login-script

Im running OSX, and every time i reboot i have to select my remote servers, hit "connect as", enter the username and password, and then login in order to use any of my scripts that access files on them.

I need...

1. a simple way in python to do this process (login on the remote server using using a user and password)
2. a simple way to check if i'm already connected to the selected machine.

Answer (score 2):

I use ssh. You can use public key authentication. This enables password less logins. And you can use ssh from python with the paramiko library.

But this: "2. a simple way to check if i'm already connected to the selected machine." is not very easy. Do you really need this?

Answer (score 0):

In depends on what you want to do after you connect to the external machine. A nice Python solution could be using a module called `paramiko`. I used it for some project I had half a year ago, here is the part of my code where I connected with another computer/server and executed a simple python file:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
IP = '...'
username = '...'
password = '...'
ssh.connect(IP, username, password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python hello.py')
ssh.close()
```

`stdin`, `stdout` and `sdterr` are lists with the inputs/outputs of the command you executed.

[Here](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/) is some good information about `paramiko`.